# Phoenix default json dates parse differently in Chrome / Firefox

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I’m trying to serve the automatic `timestamp` `inserted_at` field as json.

The problem is that Chrome and Firefox diverge in the way they parse what they are sent. The issue seems to be that by default Phoenix serves something like `"2017-01-12T19:49:000"`. This is parsed to UTC by Firefox and IE, while Chrome returns this converted to local time. Add a Z (`"2017-01-12T19:49:000Z"`) and all give local time.

As a result I have converted my code to read:

```
def render("message.json", %{message: message}) do
    %{id: message.id,
      content: message.content,
      date: Ecto.DateTime.to_iso8601(message.inserted_at)<>"Z"}
end
```

But this feels horribly hacky and there must be a better way.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that Ecto does not know if the datetime is or isn't UTC. Fortunately Ecto 2.1 has a better alternative, since it's supports the built-in calendrical types from Elixir 1.3.

There are two new types in schemas - `naive_datetime` that stores a datetime without the timezone (using Elixir's `NaiveDateTime` struct), and `utc_datetime` that stores datetimes in the UTC timezone (using Elixir's `DateTime` struct). The later serialises to iso8601 with the final `Z`.